# Displaing images from RSS feed in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, rss

I have an RSS feed with the following example item

```
<rss xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/" xmlns:wfw="http://wellformedweb.org/CommentAPI/" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:sy="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/syndication/" xmlns:slash="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/slash/" version="2.0">
<channel>
<title/>
<atom:link href="http://www.petefreeman.com/feed/" rel="self" type="application/rss+xml"/>
<link>http://www.petefreeman.com</link>
<description/>
<lastBuildDate>Wed, 21 Jan 2015 20:34:04 +0000</lastBuildDate>
<language>en-US</language>
<sy:updatePeriod>hourly</sy:updatePeriod>
<sy:updateFrequency>1</sy:updateFrequency>
<generator>http://wordpress.org/?v=4.1</generator>
<item>
<title>The Greatest Advice I’ve Ever Been Given</title>
<link>
http://www.petefreeman.com/the-greatest-advice-ive-ever-been-given/
</link>
<comments>
http://www.petefreeman.com/the-greatest-advice-ive-ever-been-given/#comments
</comments>
<pubDate>Mon, 11 Aug 2014 03:06:16 +0000</pubDate>
<dc:creator>
<![CDATA[ petefreeman14 ]]>
</dc:creator>
<category>
<![CDATA[ Uncategorized ]]>
</category>
<guid isPermaLink="false">http://www.petefreeman.com/?p=161</guid>
<description>
<![CDATA[
<img src="http://i2.wp.com/www.petefreeman.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/rabbit.jpg?fit=1024%2C1024" class="attachment-large wp-post-image" alt="rabbit" />
 <div>
 <a href="http://www.petefreeman.com/the-greatest-advice-ive-ever-been-given/"><img title="rabbit" src="http://i2.wp.com/www.petefreeman.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/rabbit.jpg?fit=200%2C200" alt="&lt;a href=&quot;http://www.petefreeman.com/the-greatest-advice-ive-ever-been-given/&quot; title=&quot;Permalink to The Greatest Advice I&#039;ve Ever Been Given&quot; rel=&quot;bookmark&quot;&gt;&lt;strong&gt;The Greatest Advice I&#8217;ve Ever Been Given&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;/a&gt;" width="" /></a>
 </div>
 *Warning: The following conversation between a fictional man and a fictional rabbit changed my life. Reader discretion is advised. &#160; &#160; Here&#8217;s how it played out. Brer Rabbit was pouting about what he had and what he didn&#8217;t have, and how he never seemed to get what he wanted. Uncle Remus wisely acknowledged Brer Rabbit [&#8230;]
]]>
</description>
<content:encoded>
<![CDATA[
<img src="http://i2.wp.com/www.petefreeman.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/rabbit.jpg?fit=1024%2C1024" class="attachment-large wp-post-image" alt="rabbit" />
 <div>
 <a href="http://www.petefreeman.com/the-greatest-advice-ive-ever-been-given/"><img title="rabbit" src="http://i2.wp.com/www.petefreeman.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/rabbit.jpg?fit=200%2C200" alt="&lt;a href=&quot;http://www.petefreeman.com/the-greatest-advice-ive-ever-been-given/&quot; title=&quot;Permalink to The Greatest Advice I&#039;ve Ever Been Given&quot; rel=&quot;bookmark&quot;&gt;&lt;strong&gt;The Greatest Advice I&#8217;ve Ever Been Given&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;/a&gt;" width="" /></a>
 </div>
 <p>*Warning: The following conversation between a fictional man and a fictional rabbit changed my life. Reader discretion is advised.</p> <p>&nbsp;</p> <p></p> <p>&nbsp;</p> <p>Here&#8217;s how it played out. Brer Rabbit was pouting about what he had and what he didn&#8217;t have, and how he never seemed to get what he wanted. Uncle Remus wisely acknowledged Brer Rabbit and said the following life-changing words &#8211; <em>&#8220;<strong>It&#8217;s not what you got. It&#8217;s what you do with what you got that counts.&#8221;</strong></em></p> <p>&nbsp;</p> <p>These 15 words changed my life. Seriously. Think about all the possessions you <del datetime="2014-08-11T02:24:50+00:00">have</del> think you have to have before you can make a change in the world. Before you can start your business. Before you are secure enough to start a family. That number is <strong>overwhelming</strong>.</p> <p>Will we ever get enough? No. And neither will Brer Rabbit. But there is a <em>second path</em>, as Uncle Remus points out. And Remus was right. When Brer Rabbit stopped taking and started making, his world turned upside down.</p> <p>We all tend to look around at our houses, cars and bank accounts and think, &#8220;what will it take for me to get x new appliance/y new luxury car/z amount of dollars.&#8221; Inevitably, our solution is to get the resources to get the new x, y or z. <strong>But this is backwards!</strong> Just like Brer Rabbit, we already have the resources we need to move forward with our lives. It&#8217;s not <em>what</em> resources we&#8217;ve got, it&#8217;s <em>what we do</em> with those resources that will affect our outcome.</p> <p>After hearing this conversation between Remus &amp; Rabbit (shoutout Grandpa for making this decades-old cartoon come to life. I love you.), I took inventory. Inventory of my bedroom, inventory of my car, inventory of my bank account. I sat down with a spreadsheet of my resources and a word document of my goals. After many connecting lines later, I had mapped out what I was going to do with what I had to get what I want. The following year, I co-founded and became CEO of a nonprofit business that paired disadvantaged elementary school students with high school mentors. And looking back? I didn&#8217;t need more influence, more money, more <em>resources</em>. All I needed was my co-founder and the guts to organize one of the most effective nonprofits our high school had ever seen.</p> <p>Lack of material want and resourcefulness are two very lucky traits I have, and they’re something that I implore more of you to focus on.</p> <hr /> <p style="text-align: center;"><em><strong>If you found value in this article, it would mean a lot to me if you tweeted @mrpetefreeman &amp; told me!</strong></em></p> <hr /> <p>I&#8217;m an innovator. You can find out more at <a href="http://www.petefreeman.com/about">wwww.petefreeman.com/about</a></p>
]]>
</content:encoded>
<wfw:commentRss>
http://www.petefreeman.com/the-greatest-advice-ive-ever-been-given/feed/
</wfw:commentRss>
<slash:comments>0</slash:comments>
</item>
```

So far I have successfully pulled the title and link! The image is a bit trickier though. My main goal is just to get the image link into a variable in my code, I think I can figure out how to display it from there but its strange. It's wrapped in a "content:encoded" block and a "[CDATA]" block and I'm not sure how to access it successfully, it certainly is not working like the others. I have tried "content:encoded" which gives me way too much and the others return nil. Here is my code

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {

    //NSLog(@"\nXML Parser:didStartElement:%@\n\t\t\tnameSpaceURI:%@\n\t\t\tqualifiedName:%@\n\t\t\tattributes:%@", elementName, namespaceURI, qName, attributeDict);
    element = elementName;

    if ([element isEqualToString:@"item"]) {

        item    = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        title   = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
        link    = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
        image   = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];           
    }
}


- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName {

    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"item"]) {

        [item setObject:title forKey:@"title"];
        [item setObject:link forKey:@"link"];
        [item setObject:image forKey:@"content:encoded"];

        [feeds addObject:[item copy]];

    }

}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string {

    if ([element isEqualToString:@"title"]) {
        [title appendString:string];

    } else if ([element isEqualToString:@"link"]) {
        [link appendString:string];
    }
    else if ([element isEqualToString:@"content:encoded"]) {
        [image appendString:string];
         NSLog(image);
    }

}

- (void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser {

    [self.tableView reloadData];

}
```

If anyone can help that would be awesome, thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I would assume that when you read in content:encoded that it had all of the html that was in the CDATA tag? Since that content isn't structured XML you would need to parse that HTML yourself to get the img from it.

Parse XML and parse the HTML in the content:encoded section